# Let $\{p_1, . . . , p_l\}$ be points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ . Show that the set $U = \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{p_1, p_2, . . . , p_l\}$ is open.

Tags: general-topology

Question is as stated in the title. I'm aware that $\mathbb R^n$ is an open (or closed) set, and I know how to prove it, but beyond that I'm stuck.

Firstly, how do I prove that the set of arbitrary points, $\{p_1, p_2, . . . , p_l\} \in \mathbb R^n$ is open? Secondly, can I use that to conclude that the difference $\mathbb R^n \setminus \{p_1, p_2, . . . , p_l\}$ is also open?

Comment: The finite point set $\{p_1, \ldots, p_l\}$ is NOT open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  My suggestion would be to pick an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}^n/ \{p_1, \ldots, p_l\}$ and put a ball around it.

Comment: I understand that now, thanks!

Comment: Another way to show it is open is to take an arbitrary $x\in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{p_1,\ldots, p_l\}=:A$ and can you find an $\varepsilon$-ball around $x$ that stays completely inside the set $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we exclude a single point in $\mathbb{R}$, say $x$, then we can represent $\mathbb{R}-\{x\}$ as $[\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (-k+x,x) ]\cup [\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (x,x+k)]$ this is open because it's a union of open intervals.  Therefore, $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x\})^c = \{x\}$ is closed.  A finite union of closed sets is closed, therefore $\{x_1,...,x_m\}$ is closed.  The same argument can be extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$.  You should actually try to work out the details for yourself.

EDIT:  The last detail in the $\mathbb{R}^1$ case is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x_1,...,x_m\}=\mathbb{R} \cap \{x_1,...,x_m\}^c =\{x_1,...,x_m\}^c $ is open because the complement of a closed set is open.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: you're very welcome, glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

I would try showing that a one point set in $\mathbb R^n$ is closed. From there, show (or use, if you already know) that a finite union of closed sets is closed. From there it follows from the definition of open and closed that $\mathbb R^n - \{p_1,...,p_n\}$ is open.